# Was Heidegger simply a Lebensreform (er)?

Tags: heidegger

Here is a little information about the  Lebensreform in English. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensreform

I am referring particularly to the time before WWI. (edit)

It is hard to say, of course, that Heidegger is "simply" anything, but part of this movement seems to have a very "pre-Socratic" nature to me. This seems to be a very "Greek" time in Germany to me.

Single sex, but also many mixed sex photographs of the time show young people are often nude, and simple. Loosely they are doing some gymnastics, but really they are free and just having fun in nature, at camp.

I am not talking about the hiking and folk elements so much as I am the nudity at camp, the fun the young people had, somehow I associate this with merely "being". The enjoyment of pure being.

I do not suggest that Heidegger cavorted around in the nude :). Perhaps he did. But he might have heard about it or saw photographs?  This was the spirit of the times and Heidegger was rather young himself then.

With all the journals of philosophy and books printed each year, I wonder if this hypothesis that Heidegger was a Lebensreform (er) has been put forth?  Or that he was influenced by this movement?

NB: when I say a "Greek time" or period in Germany, I mean such a time mainly for the younger people.

Comment: The [Lebensreform movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensreform#History) in Germany originally was linked with pacifist intelelctuals. There was a link also with [Freikörperkultur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freik%C3%B6rperkultur) naturist movement, that was banend after the Nazi Party came to power. Thus, the link seems to me a feeble one.

Comment: @mauroAllegranza Thank you. Yes, my focus would be on the period prior to WWI. I realize there are other elements, but I am trying to isolate the "Greek" elements.  What might have seemed Greek, even pre-Socractic Greek to Heidegger. The noble enjoyment of pure being.

Comment: A look at some of the photographs of the period shows not so much a "Germanic-pagan", but a "Greek-ish pagan".   Though there could certainly be overlap between the two, and Heidegger himself I think saw the Germans as carrying the Greek torch, so to speak. The new Greeks. I do not in any way mean a value-judgment in my use of the word "pagan".

Comment: Hi ! Given the intensive study of Heidegger's life - early, middle, and late - in the last 50 years, I think any association with the Lebensreform movement would have been uncovered by now. So far as I am aware, none has. (Heidegger may have loved the German countryside but I think he preferred to keep his clothes between it and himself ;)- Good question - it probes a possibility but I think you'll find it's a dead end. Best - GT

Comment: Thank you, GT!  Yes, that makes sense that there has been considerable study of the influences on Heidegger.

Comment: @mauroALLEGRANZA  Ahhh, I see what you mean now!  I was not aware of the Freikorperkultur. Thank you.